# Word for "the distilled embodiment of a contentious issue"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm thinking of something like the recent [FBI–Apple case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FBI%E2%80%93Apple_encryption_dispute), which focuses in on the precise point of departure between the two sides of an issue.  It would be used like: "the case has become a ____ of the issue".  I believe the word I've heard before is some kind of a metaphor like "litmus test" or "touchstone", but emphasizes how it cuts to the heart of the issue instead of being a simple test for a larger issue.

Comment: From your explanation, I'd guess 'paradigm' or 'archetype'--two very different focuses. Thus, I suspect neither is what you're looking for. And neither is strongly metaphorical.

Answer (score 1):

Quintessential (Adjective)

1
 :   the essence of a thing in its purest and most concentrated form

2
 :   the most typical example or representative

([Merriam Webster: Quintessential](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quintessence))

If you need a noun, some other possibilities include keystone, cornerstone, poster child, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try [yardstick](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/yardstick) (Merriam Webster)

> It means a specific idea or rule about what is acceptable or desirable that is used to judge or measure something.

Also there's [essence](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/essence) (Merriam Webster)

> Something that contains in very strong, usually concentrated, form the special qualities of the thing from which it is taken.
>
> A constituent or derivative possessing the special qualities in concentrated form.

Technically, **essence** is the result of distillation.

[distillation](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/distillation)

> the purification or concentration of a substance, the obtaining of the essence or volatile properties contained in it.

Comment: You seem to be thinking that "the case has become an **essence** of the issue" makes sense in the context of the OP's question. Maybe 'distillation' would be an improvement?

Comment: @JEL Well, distillation is used to manufacture chocolate or vanilla essence and technically, distillation captures all the good features of the whole substance, such as smell and taste, in a highly concentrated form. So by definition, "essence" is thd distilled embodiment of a substance.

Comment: Perhaps "the case **represents the essence** of the issue" would work for the OP's example? An essence pre-exists in the (metaphorical) source, so saying "the case *has become* an essence of the issue" fails the smell test (semantic dissonance); "the case is/represents a distillation of the issue" would be better, but fails on the consideration that "distilled embodiment" is already in the question title.

Comment: @JEL Point taken. "the essence of a contentious issue" is what I have to look for. I'll get on it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps 'lightning rod' is the metaphor you want:

> With a tone that approached derision, the federal government made those assertions in a court motion Friday that intensifies a battle that’s become a lightning rod in the debate over privacy versus security.

(From "[Apple v. FBI: Key Passages from the Justice Department’s Rebuttal](http://blogs.wsj.com/law/2016/02/19/apple-v-fbi-key-passages-from-the-justice-departments-rebuttal/)", bylined Jacob Gershman. In *The Wall Street Journal*, February 19, 2016.)

> The ensuing legal fight has become a **lightning rod** for a broader debate on data privacy vs. security.

(From "[Apple Vs. FBI: Israeli Firm Reportedly Will Unlock iPhone](http://www.investors.com/news/technology/apple-vs-fbi-israeli-firm-reportedly-will-unlock-iphone/)". Bylined Michelle Chandler, in *Investors Business Daily*, March 3, 2016.)

> The hearing, set for Tuesday, is the latest development in a showdown between Apple and the government that has become a **lightning rod** in the national debate over digital privacy.

(From "[US prosecutors, Apple to bring witnesses to hearing on locked iPhone](http://indianexpress.com/article/technology/tech-news-technology/us-prosecutors-apple-to-bring-witnesses-to-hearing-on-locked-iphone/)". Reuters, in *The Indian Express*, March 20, 2016.)

> The development could bring an abrupt end to the high-stakes legal showdown which has become a **lightning rod** for a broader debate on data privacy in the United States.

(From "[This Could Be the Company Helping the FBI Unlock the San Bernardino Shooter's iPhone](http://fortune.com/2016/03/23/apple-iphone-fbi-cellebrite/)", Reuters, in *Fortune*, March 23, 2016.)

Comment: "Lightning rod" means someone or something that attracts criticism or gets blamed when things go wrong. How does that fit into op's question? I'm sorry if I have got a definition that you didn't mean to be perceived. Perhaps you can define it.

Comment: @vickyace, I sure appreciate your comment.

Comment: You know, I had come across "lightning rod" when looking through a thesaurus, and I thought it could be the one I had in mind.  But the definition didn't seem to fit so I came to the same conclusion as @vickyace.  However, your quotes (thank you for those) do appear to match the usage I'm remembering, so maybe I just misinterpreted the metaphor's meaning.

Comment: @Ryan, it's interesting that the use shown in the quotes is somewhat...off key...with respect to dictionary definitions, and more in line with this prescient quote about *the cloud* from the *OED* attestations: "1860   R. W. Emerson *Worship in Conduct of Life* (London ed.) 204   The lightning-rod that disarms the cloud of its threat." The 'lightning rod' of the contemporary quotes does not disarm *the cloud* of its threat, but rather focuses the threat on a secondary, possibly irrelevant target, thus distracting attention from the real threat--loss of privacy regardless of the case outcomes.

Answer (score 0):

**crux**

[dictionary.com definition](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/crux)

> 1. a vital, basic, decisive, or pivotal point:

.

[Oxford dictionaries definition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/crux)

> 1. The decisive or most important point at issue:

To use it in a modification of your sentence: the case has gone to the crux of the issue.

.

Or you can use one of these words:

**The case embodied/epitomized/exemplified/typified/personified the issue.**